# How to resolve RemoteHostClosedError?

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping, pdfkit

I am writing a program to scrap articles of Geeks for Geeks using BeautifulSoup and pdfkit( for downloading in form of pdfs ) in Python.

While running the script I get `OSError : RemoteHostClosedError`.

I tried to solve it by recursion :

```
def PDFdownload( url , filename ):
                    try:
                        pdfkit.from_url(url,filename)
                    except OSError:
                        print('Waiting ...ResolvingRemoveHostClosedError')
                        time.sleep(2)
                        PDFdownload( url , filename)
```

Sometimes it works but sometimes it takes very long. Is there a better way to solve this?

PS - I am a newbie and I don't know anything about Socket Programming.